# explorer doesn't show item details for shell namespace extension in TILE view mode

Tags: c++, winapi, explorer, shell-extensions

I have written a NSE that makes many types of compressed archives like 7Z and RAR behave like folders (see http://zabkat.com/blog/compressed-folder-shell-extension.htm)

Most of it works well, but I can't make windows explorer ask for item properties (size/date), e.g. for tooltips, tile view mode or its details pane (the bottom part)

The IShellFolder supports GetDetailsOf and GetDetailsEx, and all standard properties like PKEY_DateCreated etc are available. The folder also supports IPropertyStoreFactory. Windows explorer shows the right columns in its detailed view mode but only shows file name in tiles view mode

what interface am I missing to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

the answer is that one needs to supply these extended properties:
PKEY_PropList_TileInfo
PKEY_PropList_PreviewDetails